# How to get the specific date of the event that has been clicked

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I've tried  the event click function in getting the date, but I can't understand the parameters that the `eventClick` is getting. This is my code

```
 eventClick: function(info) {
                    $("#calendar-modal").html("");
                    var scheduleClick="info.event.getDate()";
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar-modal');
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                            plugins: [ 'interaction', 'timeGrid' ],
                            header: {
                                left: 'prev,next today',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'timeGridDay'
                            },
                            displayEventTime:false,
                            allDaySlot: false,
                            slotEventOverlap:false,
                            eventSources:[
                               {
                               url:'http://localhost/servrevo_web/booking/getBooking',
                               method:'POST',
                               color: '#87a900',  
                               textColor: 'black'
                               }
                               ],
                    });  
                    calendar.changeView('timeGridDay',scheduleClick);
                    calendar.render();
                    $('#timeSlot').modal('show');
```

The variable `scheduleClick` is not getting anything any help?

Comment: Just to check, is this code trying to create a second calendar in addition to the existing one? Because re-creating the existing calendar when you're in the middle of clicking on an event from it would be crazy...

Comment: And if you're creating a new calendar, why bother with "changeView" as a separate method? Just set the defaultDate and defaultView options within the calendar directly.

Comment: P.S. Your definition of `scheduleClick` (`var scheduleClick="info.event.getDate()";`) makes no sense...you declared it as a string. So you are literally telling fullCalendar to use the words `info.event.getDate()` as the date. Remove the double-quote marks (`"`) from that and it will actually execute the function. That is basic JS knowledge, nothing to do with fullCalendar.

Comment: After that, `info.event.getDate()` doesn't work because the [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) doesn't have a function called "getDate()". If you want to get a date, I would guess you either want to the `start` or `end` date of the event. So `var scheduleClick = info.start` might make more sense (you don't really need getDate() specifically, as fullCalendar will [accept a Date object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing) as input, no need for a string)

Comment: Thank you,@adyson. I have 2 calendar. Im doing inserting the 2nd calndar in a modal. thank you for those tips.

Comment: info.start doesn't work. Sorry, i cant understand some codes of eventClick. that is why im asking..

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I meant `info.event.start` . Start is a property of the event object. The event object is a property of the info object. It's quite logical really. Is there something specific about the "some codes" I can help you understand?

Comment: I will really appreciate that. Thank you so much! the codes that i've said are "can eventClick return something?, Or what else does it return because i see ( eventClick: function(info){}) what does info have? can i get something in that info.)

Comment: what does info have? ... It has what is described in the documentation.  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick . There are 4 properties listed in the table there, those are the properties of the info object

Comment: And no you can't return anything from the function. Well, you could, but it would be pointless - the function gets called from somewhere inside fullCalendar's code, and so any value you return will go back to that place. fullCalendar isn't expecting and return value and isn't interested in one, so it will just ignore it. If you want to do something with the data from outside the eventClick, then you need to call your own function from within the eventClick function. This is the same with all callback functions, not just this one.